# Why does my global variable given by JRuby to my ruby script empty?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

My Ruby script:

```
def start
    print "Global variable: #{$globalVariable}"
end
```

Java code executing it:

```
    jruby = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("jruby"); // Create engine
    jruby.eval(myRubyScriptContents);   // Evaluate my ruby script
    jruby.put("$globalVariable", this);  // Give it a global variable
    Invocable invocable = (Invocable) jruby;
    invocable.invokeFunction("start");    // Call the start method to print my variable
```

Output is this:

> Global variable:

Why is my variable empty?

Comment: Which version of Java?  Which version of JRuby? Can you provide complete java code?

Comment: Hi Omega.  Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could provide a working example of your problem when posting.

Here is a working solution (note absense of dollar sign in engine `put`).

```
import javax.script.*;
class TesterApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngine jruby = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("jruby");
        jruby.eval("def start;print \"Global variable: #{$globalVariable}\";end");
        jruby.put("globalVariable", "This is a working example.");
        Invocable invocable = (Invocable) jruby;
        invocable.invokeFunction("start"); 
    }
}
```